# https security is compromised

Tags: internet-explorer, https

I have these errors in `IE9` on my site:

```
 SEC7111:  HTTPS security is compromised by res://ieframe.dll/dnserrordiagoff.htm 
 SEC7111:  HTTPS security is compromised by res://ieframe.dll/ErrorPageTemplate.css 
 SEC7111:  HTTPS security is compromised by res://ieframe.dll/errorPageStrings.js 
 SEC7111:  HTTPS security is compromised by res://ieframe.dll/httpErrorPagesScripts.js 
 SEC7111:  HTTPS security is compromised by res://ieframe.dll/noConnect.png 
 SEC7111:  HTTPS security is compromised by res://ieframe.dll/bullet.png
```

I know this error arises because of I am trying to get `http` content via `https` protocol. But I can't see anywhere in the page where this could be caused.
I investigated that this problem might be solved by customizing the browser, but this isn't a good solution.

Does anyone know what is causing these errors?

Comment: Please check if there is a JS Fallback for old IE versions. This scripts could load some http content (style, additional scripts).

Answer (score 3):

A client of mine had the `SEC7111:  HTTPS security is compromised by res://ieframe.dll/` problem recently in various versions of IE up to and including IE11 - and possibly Edge too but now it's fixed I cannot check easily - and the issue was unrelated to X-Frame-Options, all sites involved used SSL and there were no mixed http + https content errors.

In this case the root of the problem was Internet Explorer security zone trust levels. The company I work for run a large web app for a large organisation with a corporate domain, and our app is hosted using a subdomain eg `crm.egcorporate.com`.

The client also have their intranet and public website on www and other subdomains of `egcorporate.com`. They also use a 3rd party online Learning Management System eg `eglms.com` which on same pages iframes some content from crm.egcorporate.com, which worked fine on the staging environments for both systems, but in production caused errors for the corporate users but only when using IE on a machine connected to their domain controller.

The problem was because in their Active Directory group policy settings, they had `*.egcorporate.com` set to **Local intranet** security zone, and eglms.com was set to **Trusted sites** security zone. Because the production URL for our app was on a subdomain of their AD domain, it inherited *Local intranet* trust settings in IE, which meant IE would not allow the LMS at the lower *Trusted* level to iframe *intranet* content. But the daftness of IE11 is that it tries to display its `res://ieframe.dll/`... embedded error pages to tell us this, but then blocks itself from displaying its own error pages which is what the `SEC7111` errors are then telling us.

In our case the solution was for the corporate IT guys to add a more specific `crm.egcorporate.com` **Trusted sites** zone rule to their AD group policy (and have users log out + log in again), so that the iframed content and the framing site were both seen as the same trust level by IE.

The reason that we did not see the same issue in staging was because we use a URL like egcorporate.staging.mycompany.com which obviously was not covered by their intranet security zone settings.

Answer (score 1):

Another thing to check is that you **do not** have the header X-Frame-Options set to deny as show:

```
X-Frame-Options:DENY
```

Also see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options

Answer (score -1):

Make sure your content in iframe allows put it in frame.

ex: X-Frame-Options:SAMEORIGIN

ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/X-Frame-Options

Comment: I don't think this will work if your certificate is bad, but it is somewhat relevant in that if the header X-Frame-Options:DENY is present in your headers, you may see the same error.